# Angular Emit to router-outlet

Tags: angular

I have router-outlet in the parent component and want to emit from child component but the parent component function is never fired?

Child component

```
@Output() setTitle: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

ngOnInit() {
    this.setTitle.emit('test'); 
}
```

In the parent html

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div (setTitle)='setTitle($event)'></div>
    <router-outlet (setTitle)='setTitle($event)'></router-outlet>
</div>
```

parent ts file

```
setTitle(title){
    console.log(title)
}
```

Even the simple div does not work
Please help

Comment: Do you want to emit the router outlet in onClick function?

Comment: I have router-outlet in the parent. The data does not come in from the child

Comment: @user2837961 did my solution works for you?

Comment: @Vikas Yes it did. I cant thank you enough

Comment: Welcome mate :) happy to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use custom event on router-outlet directive.
The router-outlet directive has two events.
`activate` - When a component is loaded in router
`deactivate` - When a component is unloaded from router
[docs](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet)

For your scenario you could utilise `activate` event When the child component is loaded, onActivate will be triggered and you will get the component reference

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div (setTitle)='setTitle($event)'></div>
    <router-outlet (activate)='onActivate($event)'></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Via Component reference you can observe the event emitter

```
onActivate(componentReference) {
   //Below will subscribe to the searchItem emitter
   componentReference.setTitle.subscribe((data) => {
      this.setTitle(data);
   })
}
```